# Why doesn't a statement print with a for loop variable when it prints fine with another for loop variable?

Tags: batch-file

So, I'm messing around with some code and I came across a weird issue. I have a string in a file called "tests" that is "1:23195068336843541324" I want a for loop to find the 3rd character and based off of that find a certain amount of characters starting with the 7th character. In this case I want to find the 7th and 8th character. So I came up with this nested for loop:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
    FOR /F %%j IN ('FINDSTR /C:"%%i:" tests.txt') DO (
        SET PH=%%j
        SET mon=!PH:~2,1!
        ECHO !mon!
        SET test%%i=!PH:~6,%mon%!
        ECHO !test1!))
```

The ECHO statements are purely for debugging so I can see what is set to what.

But everytime it outputs `ECHO is OFF` because `test1` is never set. I recreated it with this loop:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET test=123
SET number=2
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO (
SET t%%i=!test:~1,%number%!
ECHO !t1!)
```

and it works fine. If I put a number in for `mon` in the first loop it also works fine. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Use your for variables in alphabetic order.

Comment: `PH` has to be set before `mon` because `mon` depends on `PH`. Either way, alphabetical order shouldn't matter.

Comment: You seem to be confused on how delayed expansion works.

Comment: I'm confused on how I could use any of those variables in a different order since they are dependent on each other and the syntax requires `PH` before `mon`. An example of this would help clear my confusion.

Comment: I think you did not understand my comment earlier about using the `FOR` variables in alphabetic order.  You listed your environmental variables in your comments.  That of course doesn't matter.  But in some instances if you use `%%j` in the outer loop and use `%%i` in the inner loop, the inner loop could destroy the outer loop `%%j` if you were using the `TOKENS` option in the inner `FOR` loop.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that advice.

Comment: Regardless of all that.  Don't you think it makes logical sense to keep track of your `FOR` variables in alphabetic order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are attempting to do.  I really don't understand why you are doing what you are doing which is half the battle when trying to help someone code something.

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%j IN (1,1,5) DO (
    FOR /F %%i IN ('FINDSTR /C:"%%j:" tests.txt') DO (
        SET PH=%%i
        SET mon=!PH:~2,1!
        ECHO mon=!mon!
        FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ("!mon!") do SET test%%j=!PH:~6,%%G!
        ECHO test%%j=!test%%j!
    )
)
```

Comment: My use case is extremely obscure and hard to describe, but you managed to create a solution for it. Thank you. The only thing is I do not understand the code. What does adding that third for loop do? Why does that fix my problem?

Comment: All comes down to delayed expansion.  You can't use delayed expansion within delayed expansion.  You can't use: `%mon%` because it requires delayed expansion to use it.  And you can't do this either: `SET test%%i=!PH:~6,!mon!!`.  So you need some way to get the variable expanded so you can use it as your substring length.

Comment: Since `mon` only contains a simple integer, you could simplify your approach by replacing the innermost `for /F` loop by a standard `for` loop, like this: `for %%G in ("!mon!") do set test%%j=!PH:~6,%%~G!`...

Comment: @aschipfl, you are right.  I am totally disregarding my normal best practice on when to use `FOR` and `FOR /F`.  LOL!